# Delete all cookies except those from certain sites

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

With Chrome, how to **delete all cookies except those from a custom list of whitelisted sites** (e.g. google.com, stackoverflow.com, etc. to keep them logged in)?

I know the "Clear browsing data" > Advanced dialog in Chrome, but I don't see how to customize which cookies to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deleting all cookies, Chrome is missing the ability of Firefox to keep
a whitelist to save cookie information from deletion.
Adding this feature then requires  an extension.

You could use the extension
[Vanilla Cookie Manager](https://github.com/laktak/vanilla-chrome),
described as:

> A Cookie Whitelist Manager that helps protect your privacy.
> Automatically removes unwanted cookies. Cookies can be used for
> authentication, storing your site preferences or anything else that
> can be saved as text data. Unfortunately they can also be used to
> track you.
>
> You could turn off cookies completely or just shut off third-party
> cookies. But that would also keep out useful cookies that many web
> apps rely upon to work (like Google Mail or Calendar).
>
> With Vanilla you can select which cookies you want to keep on a
> whitelist. All unwanted cookies are deleted automatically (or manually
> if you prefer).
>
> If you close your browser often, follow the "recommended usage" on the
> options page to get rid of unwanted cookies whenever you close Chrome.
> If you seldom close you browser you should let Vanilla automatically
> delete unwanted cookies after 30 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by going to the lock in the address bar and clicking "Cookies". A little dialog will pop up and you can block or remove cookies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is only for the currently viewed website. "The following cookies were set when you viewed *this* page". I'm looking for a way to delete all cookies stored in my browser, except those from accounts.google.com, stackoverflow.com and a few others.

Comment: That is true, yes. If I can find a way to do it for all sites, I'll edit it in.