# Is there any way to whitelist specific cookies in a browser?

Tags: security, browser, browser-addons, privacy, cookies

Is there any way to whitelist specific cookies when browsing? I know some things (chromium's built-in settings, umatrix) allow you to generally block cookies, and whitelist certain domains, but not individual cookies (or even parts of cookies?). By cookies I also include any other feature (localstorage, cache) that can be (mis)used to act like cookies.
I'm mostly interested in answers relating to chromium(-based browsers) or firefox(-based browsers).

Comment: What browser?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Please help confirm which browser are you using. Meanwhile, here is a similar thread discussed how to delete all cookies except from certain sites in Google Chrome, please kindly check if it was helpful to you: [Delete all cookies except those from certain sites](https://superuser.com/questions/1572039/delete-all-cookies-except-those-from-certain-sites)

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: @Sunny That's just on a per-domain basis, and it seems to be deleting cookies rather than preventing them from entering/leaving the browser.