# Delete all cookies except those from certain sites with Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, cookies

With Firefox, **how to delete all cookies except those from a custom list of whitelisted sites**? (eg. google.com, stackoverflow.com... – I want to stay logged-in)

I know the "Clear all history" dialog in Firefox (see below), but I don't see how to customize *which* cookies to delete.

Since cookies are highly important security-wise, I would be glad to find a solution *without* a third-party browser extension, maybe with an internal Firefox option like `about:config`?

Note: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1572039/delete-all-cookies-except-those-from-certain-sites) is a solution for Chrome.

[image]

Note 2: *"Active logins"* seems to be irrelevant here: *if you entered a username and password for a site that uses HTTP basic authentication since you last opened Firefox, that login is considered "active". Clearing this will log you out of all sites that use this authentication method. It will not log you out of websites that use cookies to store login status.*

Comment: Why don't you want to delete everything except Active logins ? And maybe Site settings? This allows you to stay logged in but will clear all the remaining junk

Comment: does [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1280262) help?

Comment: @1NN do you mean I should check the box "Cookies" but leave the checkbox "Active logins" unchecked?

Comment: Hmm. just to be sure, i've checked. Its better you [read this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox). For your original question, try the link on my second comment

Comment: Yes I already know these techniques @1NN, but it does not offer the ability in Firefox to delete all cookies except cookies from, say, stackoverflow.com, google.com. NB: *"Active logins"* seems to be something else: *if you entered a username and password for a site that uses HTTP basic authentication since you last opened Firefox, that login is considered "active". Clearing this will log you out of all sites that use this authentication method. It will not log you out of websites that use cookies to store login status.*

Answer (score 3):

The following can be deducted from other answers. It is not a "one click" but rather a "four clicks" solution, but it allows you to choose the moment in which to delete the cookies:

- Go to *Settings > Privacy & Security > Cookies and Site Data*
- Next to *"Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed"*, open the "*Manage Exceptions"* dialogue. Insert the websites from which you want to preserve cookies. Make sure to use the "Allow" option for the cookies you want to persist.

Now, any time you want to delete cookies, do the following:

- Go to *Settings > Privacy & Security > Cookies and Site Data*, and check the *"Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed"* option.
- Close Firefox.
- Restart firefox, and in settings, uncheck the *"Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed"* option.
- Cookies will now continue to persist restarts unless you check the option again.

**Notes:**

- The "Manage Exceptions" settings are persistent.
- Use Domain names `https:\\mydomain.com` to include subdomains such as `https:\\sample.mydomain.com`
- In case you do "clear history": (A) keeping "cookies" checked, will clear all cookies, even those for whom you've set exceptions. (B) If you leave the "Site settings" checked, this will clear your cookies exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Install the extension: Cookie AutoDelete
Here is the [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/)

Comment: It might be a good solution, but as said in the question, I prefer to analyze first if there is a solution that doesn't require to trust an (unknown) third-party browser extension managing our cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You can let all cookies expire when Firefox is closed by:

In *Settings > Privacy & Security > Cookies and Site Data*
check "Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed".

You can create an exception rule for some websites on the same
Settings page by the "Manage Exceptions…" button, where you need
to specify these websites with an exact URL, and mark as Allow.

Note that the Allow exception only works when using
"Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed".
Without this option, deleting cookies otherwise only removes the
cookies from the websites marked as Block.

Source :
[Delete all cookies when Firefox closes except some specific ones](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1308719).
(Note that some comments in this post say that this
may not work with the latest Firefox version.)

Comment: Good idea @harrymc, I will try this! What do you mean by "exact URL"? For example to stay logged-in in stackoverflow.com and superuser.com, which URLs would you add as exceptions?

Comment: I suppose like `https://superuser.com` (I'm unclear if the terminating slash is required).

Comment: When I enter `google.com`, it automatically populates `http://google.com` and `https://google.com` but of course not `mail.google.com`, etc. Does this mean we have to add manually every subdomain in the list?

Comment: The documentation says that the URL must be exact. You could add the subdomains, or test to find that out by the empirical (hard) way.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, close to @harrymc's solution:

```
about:preferences#privacy
```

*Settings > Privacy & Security > Cookies and Site Data > Manage Data*

Then select the individual cookies to be deleted, *Remove*, and done!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since this looks like it solved, please mark this as your chosen solution and award your bounty to whom you like, so others (as me) won't get confused over it and think you're still looking for an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @1NN Maybe there is still a better or handier solution, so I will wait a few days before closing it.

Comment: @1NN After using it twice, my solution is not very handy, because you have to *manually* pick in this list every cookie that you want to preserve, and delete all the rest. A better solution with a whitelisting would be far better ("Delete all cookies now except those from: [TEXTBOX]")